# Does an XQD USB-C Card Reader exist?

Tags: memory-card, card-reader

I want to be able to read photographs from my XQD cards via my new MacBook Pro which has only USB-C ports.

Does any card reader exist to allow me to access my photographs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with photography.

Comment: @Tetsujin Disagreed. XQD cards are used basically exclusively for photography & videography. It's fairly safe to assume that the data contained on OP's XQD cards came from a camera (chances are, probably a Nikon, to boot).

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge no such device exists. You're stuck using a [USB-3.1 to USB-C adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GGKYXVE) until someone decides to link two niche devices to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The successor to XQD, [CFexpress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFexpress) (also known as **CFX**) is backward-compatible with XQD. The first iterations will use the XQD form factor and connector. However, CFX is designed to use PCIe 3 / NMVe host interface. As such, CFX readers will probably rely on Thunderbolt 3 (or comparably fast interfaces in the future).

Your MacBook Pro's ports are dual-mode USB 3.1 and Thunderbolt 3, over a USB-C connector. So for high-capacity high-speed media connections, you should probably be looking at Thunderbolt 3 interfaces.

One such CFX reader that relies on Thunderbolt 3 is the [Atechflash Blackjet TX-1CXQ](https://www.atechflash.com/blackjet-tx1cxq). (Rather, it *will* use Thunderbolt 3, when it is available on the market. The manufacturer previously had announced the VX-1CXQ as available 3rd quarter 2018, but the product page is no longer available.)

[Blackjet's UX-1 Cinema Dock](https://www.atechflash.com/blackjet-ux1) supports XQD 2.0, and also connects via a Thunderbolt 3 USB-C connection. However, at $425, it seems a bit pricey.

[Prograde Digital has demonstrated a 1 TB CXExpress card with a prototype CFExpress/XQD reader](https://www.imaging-resource.com/articles/exclusive-review-progrades-new-1400-mb-s-cfexpress-card-is-memorys-brave-ne) that also connects via Thunderbolt 3. However, their anticipated September 2018 release date for both card and reader has passed.